# Ejs helper for templates

Tags: node.js, templates, ejs

I'm wondering how to change this code:

`<% include ../../assets/linker/templates/box %>`

To something smarter like `<% template('box') %>`. Is that possible? Maybe using helpers? I'm not confident because of the `include` keyword, it must be interprated by EJS, not by node.js so I'm not sure what's the good approach here.

Comment: you always can rewrite ejs as you want - it's just module

Comment: I don't like rewriting/forking modules when I can avoid it, it would be better/simpler/cleaner to add some kind of helper that does the trick for me.